# Call stack in compiled matlab

Tags: matlab, callstack, matlab-compiler

In matlab one can use dbstack to retrieve the call stack at the current time, however dbstack is not available in standalone compiled versions of matlab programs, is there an alternative to get the call stack, or at least the function calling the current function? I want to write a facility function that needs to know by who it was called, but a full call stack would be preferable.

Comment: Do you know if your compiler allows you to use MException objects for error handling? If so, have I got a jury-rig for you! ;)

Comment: I though of doing that as well, raising an exception in a try/catch and grabbing the call stack from there. ;) Unfortunately, I've got a seriously ancient version of matlab I need to work with; no MException and lasterror doesn't even return the call stack... :(

Comment: Wow, sounds like you're between a rock and a hard place. I can't think of any better solutions right now, so I'm just going to update my answer with the error-handling solution. Even though you can't use it because of your older MATLAB version, it may help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which version of MATLAB are you using? I guess it has to be older than 7.1 if LASTERROR isn't returning stack info (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/f30-1008061.html#f30-1007471).

Comment: I'm working with 6.5 release 13, as I said seriously ancient... :/

Comment: Well, I guess it's not as bad as still using 4.2c ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983710/differences-between-matlab-4-2c-and-the-lastest-one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's where the solutions stand so far:

- As you mentioned, the function [DBSTACK](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dbstack.html) is on the [list of functions that are not supported by the MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/compiler/br2cqa0-20.html), so it can't be used.
- You also mentioned in a comment that even though the function [EVALIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html) isn't on the unsupported function list your compiler still won't allow you to use it. That ended up rejecting some of the previous solutions I suggested.
- Having to maintain your own stack trace by passing arguments along the chain of function calls (or possibly by storing them in a [global variable](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/global.html)) is not an ideal option due to the complexity and extra work it would take to maintain.

However, I have one more possible solution that I think is the "cleanest" one yet: using the error handling mechanisms to get at the stack trace. This will vary based on the MATLAB version you are using...

### MATLAB Versions 7.5 (R2007b) and newer:

New error-handling capabilities in the form of the [MException class](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l448-1.html) were [introduced in Version 7.5](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/brb410y-1.html#brb79wb-1). You can get information about the stack trace from MException objects by creating and throwing a "dummy" exception, then immediately catching it and accessing the [`stack` field](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bq9l448-1.html#bq9no0f-1). If you do the following in a function:

```
try
  throw(MException('phony:error',''));
catch ME
  callerStack = {ME.stack.name};
end
```

Then the cell array `callerStack` will contain the names of all the functions in the call stack, with the current function name in the first element and the top-most caller name in the last element.

### MATLAB Versions 7.1 (R14SP3) through 7.4 (R2007a):

For these earlier versions you can use the [ERROR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/error.html) function to throw an error and the [LASTERROR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/lasterror.html) function to capture the error and get the stack information:

```
try
  error('phony:error','');
catch
  s = lasterror;
  callerStack = {s.stack.name};
end
```

### MATLAB Versions 7.0.4 (R14SP2) and earlier:

Unfortunately, the [LASTERROR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/lasterror.html) function only started returning stack trace information in [MATLAB Version 7.1](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/f30-1008061.html#f30-1007471), so there is no version of the above solutions that I can come up with for earlier MATLAB versions.

Comment: Unfortunately is seems that, although evalin is not in the list of unsupported function, it is not supported in stand-alone mode, at least according to my mcc...

Comment: @wich: Hmmm, that's a problem. I think you may then have to go with the more difficult alternative I mentioned above, which is to maintain a "stack" of your own by passing an extra variable to each function containing a list of previous callers.

Comment: yeah, but that sort of defeats the purpose of having a facility function if half it's implementation is spread out over the whole program... I'm afraid I've run into a wall here